# Android JetpackCompose motion layout has content out of bounds

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-motionlayout, android-motionscene

Now my content of the "LazyColumn" does not scroll to the bottom.
I should have 60 (0-59) items visible.

However when my header is open I can only see 50 (cannot scroll more down)
[image]
[image]

Layout inspector shows the view under:
[image]

NOTE: This works perfectly fine on a Pixel3 or non foldable phones. What am I doing wrong?

I have the following motionlayout:

```
MotionLayout(
                    motionScene = MotionScene(content = motionScene),
                    motionLayoutState = motionState,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(Color.LightGray)
                        .constrainAs(motion) {
                            top.linkTo(filters.bottom)
                        }
                ) {

                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .layoutId("header")
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.xelionMainColor))
                    )
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxHeight()
                            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.xelionMainColor))
                            .layoutId("contentBg")
                    )

                    Text(
                        text = item.commonName,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .layoutId("title")
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.xelionMainColor)),
                        fontSize = 22.sp,
                        style = TextStyle(
                            fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                            color = colorResource(id = R.color.white)
                        ),
                    )

                    updateAddressableExtras(item, activity)

                    Box(
                        Modifier
                            .layoutId("avatarBox")
                            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.grey_avatar))
                    ) {
                        avatarManager.LoadInCompose(src = AvatarSource.from(item), 8.dp, 128.dp)
                        composableHandler.StatusComposable(R.drawable.ic_square_phone_not_available, 128.dp)

                    }
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .layoutId("actions")
                            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.xelionMainColor))
                            .padding(0.dp)
                    ) {
                        composableHandler.ExpandableContent(
                            item = item,
                            listener = listener,
                            isFromAddressable = true
                        )
                    }

                    IconButton(
                        onClick = { onBack?.invoke() },
                        modifier = Modifier.layoutId("back"),
                    ) {
                        Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, null, tint = Color.White)
                    }
                    if (!isOverview) {
                        IconButton(
                            onClick = {
                                isExpanded = !isExpanded
                                if (!isExpanded) isFiltersExpanded = false
                            },
                            modifier = Modifier.layoutId("menu"),
                        ) {
                            Icon(painterResource(R.drawable.baseline_more_vert_24), null, tint = Color.White)
                        }
                    }

                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxHeight()
                            .layoutId("contentBox")
                            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.inbox_list_color))
                    ) {
                        content()
                    }
                }
```

Where content is:

```
  content: @Composable () -> Unit,
```

And I add a LazyColumn in it from different fragments

```
val listItems = ArrayList<String>()
                        repeat(60){
                            listItems.add("TEST $it")
                        }
                        LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                            items(listItems){
                                Text(it)
                            }
                        }
```

This is my motion scene:

```html
{
  ConstraintSets: {
    start: {
      header: {
        width: "spread",
        height: 150,
        top: ['parent', 'top', 0],
        start: ['parent', 'start', 0],
        end: ['parent', 'end', 0],
        translationY: 0,
      },
      avatarBox: {
        width: 128,
        height: 128,
        top: ['parent', 'top', 5],
        start: ['parent', 'start', 0],
        end: ['parent', 'end', 0],
        centerHorizontally: 'parent'
      },
      contentBg: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 'spread',
        start: ['parent', 'start',0],
        end: ['parent', 'end',0],
        top: ['parent','top', 150],
        bottom: ['parent','bottom'],
      },
      back: {
        width: 38,
        height: 38,
        start: ['parent', 'start', 16],
        top: ['parent', 'top'],
      },
      menu: {
        width: 38,
        height: 38,
        end: ['parent', 'end', 16],
        top: ['parent', 'top', 0],
      },
      title: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 'wrap',
        start: ['parent', 'start'],
        end: ['parent', 'end'],
        top: ['parent','top',140],
      },
      actions: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 50,
        start: ['parent', 'start',0],
        end: ['parent', 'end',0],
        top: ['extraLayout','bottom',4],
      },
      workLayout: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 'wrap',
        start: ['parent', 'start',0],
        end: ['parent', 'end',0],
        top: ['title','bottom',4],
      },
      jobTitleLayout: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 'wrap',
        start: ['parent', 'start',0],
        end: ['parent', 'end',0],
        top: ['workLayout','bottom',4],
      },
      extraLayout: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 'wrap',
        start: ['parent', 'start',0],
        end: ['parent', 'end',0],
        top: ['jobTitleLayout','bottom',4],
      },
      contentBox: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 'spread',
        start: ['parent', 'start',0],
        end: ['parent', 'end',0],
        top: ['actions','bottom', 0],
        bottom: ['parent','bottom']
      }
    },
    end: {
      header: {
        width: "spread",
        height: 150,
        top: ['parent', 'top', 0],
        start: ['parent', 'start', 0],
        end: ['parent', 'end', 0],
        translationY: -140,
      },
      avatarBox: {
        width: 32,
        height: 32,
        top: ['parent', 'top', 5],
        start: ['parent', 'start', 50],
      },
      contentBg: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 'spread',
        start: ['parent', 'start'],
        end: ['parent', 'end'],
        top: ['parent','top'],
        bottom: ['parent','bottom'],
      },
      back: {
        width: 38,
        height: 38,
        start: ['parent', 'start', 16],
        top: ['parent', 'top'],
      },
      menu: {
        width: 38,
        height: 38,
        end: ['parent', 'end', 16],
        top: ['parent', 'top', 0],
      },
      title: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 'wrap',
        start: ['avatarBox', 'end'],
        end: ['menu', 'start'],
        top: ['parent','top',6],
      },
      actions: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 50,
        start: ['parent', 'start',0],
        end: ['parent', 'end',0],
        top: ['extraLayout','bottom',4],
      },
      workLayout: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 0,
        start: ['parent', 'start',0],
        end: ['parent', 'end',0],
        top: ['title','bottom',4],
      },
      jobTitleLayout: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 0,
        start: ['parent', 'start',0],
        end: ['parent', 'end',0],
        top: ['workLayout','bottom',4],
      },
      extraLayout: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 0,
        start: ['parent', 'start',0],
        end: ['parent', 'end',0],
        top: ['jobTitleLayout','bottom',4],
      },
      contentBox: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 'spread',
        start: ['parent', 'start'],
        end: ['parent', 'end'],
        top: ['actions','bottom',0],
        bottom: ['parent','bottom'],
      },
    },
  },
  Transitions: {
    default: {
      from: 'start',
      to: 'end',
      onSwipe: {
        anchor: 'contentBg',
        direction: 'up',
        side: 'top',
      },
    }
  }

}
```